# output for C++ virtual function

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I got quite confused about the output of the following code. The output is

```
A::Fun
C::Do
```

Could anyone explain why this happened? Any help would be appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A {
    private:
        int nVal;
    public:
        void Fun()
        { cout << "A::Fun" << endl; }
        void Do()
        { cout << "A::Do" << endl; }
};
class B:public A {
    public:
        virtual void Do()
        { cout << "B::Do" << endl; }
};
class C:public B {
    public:
    void Do( )
    { cout << "C::Do" <<endl; }
    void Fun()
    { cout << "C::Fun" << endl; }
};
void Call(B & p) {
    p.Fun(); p.Do();
}
int main() {
    C c; Call(c);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Fun` function is not virtual in any base-class. In the function `Call` all the compiler knows about is the `A::Fun` function, it doesn't know about the `C` class. All it knows is that you have a reference to a `B` object, and there is no `B::Fun` so it looks in the parent class and find the `A::Fun` function.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! It helps a lot!